# Finding first word after punctuation

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find words the first word after the punctuation. I know that i am suppose to use .split() to do it, and i tried it out too, like this:

```
longstring = "Hello my name is ryan.We are new to python, and would like to learn more. So lets start."
newstring=longstring.split()
```

I want to get a list with this information:

```
['Hello', 'We', 'So']
```

Is there an efficient way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Regarding your question:
Could you edit your question to show what you have tried so far and what didn't work the way you expected? Maybe even provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the sentence on punctuation

```
import re
text = " T?e  qu!ck ' brown 1 fox! jumps-.ver. the 'lazy' doG?  !"
sentences = re.split('(?<=[.!?]) +',text)
```

Split each sentence into words

```
for sentence in sentences:
    words = sentence.split()
    # Get the first word
    print(words[0])
```

You could then create a method to perform this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line to do so with no regular expression

```
import string
print(' '.join(word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in longstring.split()))
```

but strongly recommend DogEatDog way for a simple reason .

in case of your `longstring` this way will not detect the `ryan.We` and keep it the same way , but if you have a space between like `ryan. We` then its all good .

the result with no space will be like the following

`Hello my name is ryan.We are new to python and would like to learn more So lets start`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach allready laid the groundwork for a concise solution.

```
# split longstring along punctuation
sentences = longstring.split(".")
# use list comprehension to split each sentence into words
new_strings = [sentence.split()[0] for sentence in sentences if sentence != '']

# the if-statement at the end is necessary to avoid splitting an empty sentence
```